# How to access the global status from several vue.js components

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to create multiple characters in split components. My question is how can I call that global variable without repeating code. I have an array with 10 characters.

**index.js**

```
 state: {
characters: [],
charactersFilter: []},
 mutations: {
setCharacters(state, payload){
  state.characters = payload
},
setCharactersFilter(state, payload){
  state.charactersFilter = payload
}},
 actions: {
async getCharacters({commit}){
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2')
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
    commit('setCharacters' , data.results)
    commit('setCharactersFilter' , data.results)
  }
  
  
  catch (error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}},
```

**ListCharacters.vue**

```
export default {
components:{
     CardCharacter},

setup(){
const store = useStore()
const characters = computed(() => {
    return store.state.charactersFilter
})

 onMounted(() => {
    store.dispatch('getCharacters')
})

return {
    characters
}}}
```

**html de LisCharacters**

```
 <div class="characters">
    

          <h1>{{characters[0].name}}</h1> 
        
      </div>
```

what I want is to create another component similar to ListCharacters but naming the array 1 instead of zero. But I don't know how to access the character characters from another component without repeating all the defaults code.

I have managed to access the data of array 1 using **.this**

But when trying to access the name in this way.

```
 <h1>{{this.$store.state.characters[1].name}}</h1>
```

It gives me an error telling me that it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to repeat the code... it is much more readably and not an anti-pattern.

Also you should not access the stores state outside of the store itself.

The better way would be to get the state of the variable via [Getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html)